# ¿Porqué Javascript no me reconoce el "mayor que" en una condición?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema cuando hago la condición de "mayor que", las variables me las toma como int porque cuando hago una operación matemática todo bien, pero cuando hago esa condición no me reconoce ni el "mayor que" ni el "menor que", solo reconoce el "igual que". No comprendo a qué se debe este error en las condiciones lógicas, la variable "data" la tomo de un input tipo date. Siempre me envía a False.

```
    let data = document.getElementById("date").value;

    var yearBorth = parseInt(data.slice(0, 4));
    var monthBorth = parseInt(data.slice(5, 7));
    var dayBorth = parseInt(data.slice(8));

    var hoy = new Date();
    var dd = hoy.getDate();
    var mm = hoy.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = hoy.getFullYear();

    var dia = parseInt(dd); //Por si no reconoce a dd como integer, mejor lo convierto

    if (dia > dayBorth) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "OK";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "FALSE";
 }
```

Comment: Tu problema es que casi siempre llegas al FALSE??

Comment: Sí porque no hace la condición, aunque el día ingresado sea mayor que el actual.

Comment: Revisa día y dayBorth en la consola antes de la comparación

Comment: `parseInt(date)`, donde `date` sea una variable de tipo `Date` siempre devolverá el día del mes de la fecha `date`. ¿Es esto lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto resuelve tu problema:

```js
function solve() {
    // fecha actual - 5 días (hardcoded)
    const dateElement = document.querySelector('#date');
    dateElement.valueAsDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 5));
    
    const selectedDate = new Date(dateElement.valueAsDate);

    const selectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();
    const selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
    const selectedDay = selectedDate.getDate();
      
    const today = new Date();  
    const todayDay = today.getDate();  
    const todayMonth = today.getMonth();
    const todayYear = today.getFullYear();
      
    console.log(todayDay, selectedDay)  
    if (todayDay > selectedDay) {
      console.log(true)
    } else {
      console.log(false)
    }
}

solve()
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
```

La diferencia con su código es que con la propiedad `valueAsDate` estoy recibiendo una fecha directamente y así no tengo que seccionar el string para obtener las partes que componen la fecha.

Ahora si lo que necesita es validar que la fecha seleccionada sea menor a la actual, esta es una solución:

```js
const selectedDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 5));  // Para pruebas sólamente
const currentDate = new Date()
console.log(selectedDate, currentDate)
console.log(selectedDate.getTime() < currentDate.getTime())
```